# HidLibrary, Get Serial Number from USB device

Tags: c#, hid

I am using the following toolbox: [HidLibrary](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary)

Because I am beginner I just like to know how to get Serial Number from USB device.

Inside .dll is defined:

```
public bool ReadSerialNumber(out byte[] data)
        {
            data = new byte[64];
            IntPtr hidHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (IsOpen)
                    hidHandle = Handle;
                else
                    hidHandle = OpenDeviceIO(_devicePath, NativeMethods.ACCESS_NONE);

                success = NativeMethods.HidD_GetSerialNumberString(hidHandle, ref data[0], data.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error accessing HID device '{0}'.", _devicePath), exception);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hidHandle != IntPtr.Zero && hidHandle != Handle)
                    CloseDeviceIO(hidHandle);
            }

            return success;
        }
```

How to call the method to get the SN of device? I try but without success. I did not yet works with "out byte[]". What is meaning behind "out byte"?

Please for help!

Answer (score 2):

To call the method you can use the following:

```
var hidDevice = ...;
byte[] data;

var result = hidDevice.ReadSerialNumber(out data);
```

I assume result will be true if the method succeeded, and false if it failed. If it succeeded I'd expect the `data` variable to be populated with the data you need.

Also, if you are unsure of what `out` means in this context see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) page on the topic.